# Detect long press on "virtual" back-key

Tags: android

havent found a solution yet.
I want to detect a long press on the "virtual" back-key, the one you find at the galaxy s2 for example.

I tried to detect the onKeyDown-events (which works) when the user presses the button and the onKeyUp-events when the user leaves the button but the virtual key is firing onKeyUp-events all the time.

I also tried to override the onKeyLongPress-method but this havent helped.

```
 @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        mBackKeyDownTime = event.getEventTime();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        mBackKeyUpTime = event.getEventTime();
        final long delta = mBackKeyUpTime - mBackKeyDownTime;
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried?

Answer (score 6):

try with this...

```
    int LONG_PRESS_TIME = 5000; // Time in miliseconds
    Handler handler;
    Runnable longPressed;

    handler = new Handler();
    longPressed = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    Log.d("LogTag", "Long Pressed");
    }
};

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
     {
             handler.postDelayed(longPressed, LONG_PRESS_TIME);
         return true;
     }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
 {
     if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
     {
         handler.removeCallbacks(longPressed);
         return true;
     }
     return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
 }
```